# Adding a comment to a excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I'm having real difficulties adding a comment to a cell.

I'm calling the following sub

```
Sub ValidationError(row As Long, column As Integer, ErrorLine As String)

Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).AddComment ErrorLine

End Sub
```

**But I always get a 1004 error, saying "Application or object error" (this is translated, original message: "Anwendungs- oder objektdefinierter Fehler")**

The sub is called using

```
Call ValidationError(8, 9, "Text string")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Best

Comment: hello can you please try this: `Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).AddComment Text:=ErrorLine`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code should work if the target cell does not contain a comment. 
You can change the procedure to clear existing comments first:

```
Sub ValidationError(row As Long, column As Integer, ErrorLine As String)

Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).ClearComments
Tabelle1.Cells(row, column).AddComment ErrorLine

End Sub
```